# Is there away to write a function to filter a nested array with Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, angular-cli

I want to  write a function to filter a nested array. For example I want to be able to filter the product using the size, color in the nested array of products.

I have a sample code hosted here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-array-filtering

Comment: what you mean in nested array, as i see here your array is not nested but flat, you mean that once you filtered with searchName, then to filter with size and color?

Comment: @onik So I am trying to filter the product with size and color in the variants array.